# CustomValidator fires on the client but the validation control does not render when validation fails

Tags: asp.net

I have a simple: If the 'yes' radio button is checked than make the text box required situation.  I have supplied both client and server-side validation.  What I'm finding is that:

1. Client validation is firing and displaying failure correctly via an alert message.
2. The validation control never renders an error message and the server is hit.
3. When the server is hit and validation fails, the control renders the proper error message.

Why is the client working correctly in terms of validating, but not rendering an error message and continuing on to the server?

```
asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    function testClientValidation(src, args) {
        if ($('#<%=rblstTest.ClientID%>' + ' input:checked').length == 1) {
            if ($('#<%=rblstTest.ClientID%>' + ' input:checked').val().toLowerCase() == "yes") {
                args.isValid = !($('#<%=txtTest.ClientID%>').val() == "");  
            } else {
                args.isValid = true;
            }
        } else {
            args.isValid = true;
        }

        alert(args.isValid);
    }
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<div>
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblstTest" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList> 

<asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server"/>

<asp:CustomValidator ID="cust" ControlToValidate="rblstTest" 
                                OnServerValidate="testSeverValidation" 
                                ClientValidationFunction="testClientValidation" 
                                Display="Dynamic" 
                                ErrorMessage="Error!" runat="server"/>

 <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkSubmit" Text="Submit"  />
 </div>  
 </asp:Content>
```

Comment: The answer been accepted is not useful at all for future users. Reason being, the Client Side code is sending the user to Server(Code Behind) on either clicking Yes or No. But this should not be the case. User should move in the Code Behind in case the page is validated correctly at Client Side. You are requested to kindly conduct the review again

Comment: @Guest The problem as I understand from the question is that, even if the client validation fails the error is not displayed and postback is done. That is because the value true or false is set to the wrong member of the args parameter. Once set to correct one 'IsValid' and if the value is false the submission of the page to server is stopped and error is displayed

Comment: In OP case it always redirect to server. Either validated or not

Comment: That is the problem which my answer solved. The problem he asked was not with respect to his validation logic. It was with respect to, if false is displayed why is the page still posting back. For which My answer explained that he is using the wrong variable. It solved his problems and hence he marked it answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `args.IsValid` instead of `args.isValid`

```
function testClientValidation(src, args) {
        if ($('#<%=rblstTest.ClientID%>' + ' input:checked').length == 1) {
            if ($('#<%=rblstTest.ClientID%>' + ' input:checked').val().toLowerCase() == "yes") {
                args.IsValid = !($('#<%=txtTest.ClientID%>').val() == "");  
            } else {
                args.IsValid = true;
            }
        } else {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }

        alert(args.IsValid);
    }
```

Comment: @Beavis - I checked this code and the Original code posted. Why it should send the user to Server on either clicking the Yes or No button? Shouldn't it reach `code behind` once the `Validation` check is completed at `Client side` first?

Answer (score 0):

I added a `Hidden Field` newly added.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function testClientValidation(src, args) {
        debugger;
        if (document.getElementById('<%= hdn.ClientID %>').value == '1') {
            var txtBox = document.getElementById('<%= txtTest.ClientID%>');
            if (txtBox.value == '') {
                document.getElementById('cust').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('cust').innerHTML = 'Error!'
                document.getElementById('<%= hdn.ClientID %>').value = "1";
                args.IsValid = false;
                return false;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('cust').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('cust').innerHTML = '';
                document.getElementById('<%= hdn.ClientID %>').value = "0";
                args.IsValid = true;
            }
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('cust').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('cust').innerHTML = '';
            document.getElementById('<%= hdn.ClientID %>').value = "0";
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
        return true;
    }


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("span input[type='radio']").click(function () {
            debugger;
            if ($(this).val() == 'Yes') {
                document.getElementById('<%= hdn.ClientID %>').value = "1";
                if (document.getElementById('<%= txtTest.ClientID%>').value == '') {
                    Page_IsValid = false;
                    document.getElementById('<%= hdn.ClientID %>').value = "1";
                }
                else {
                    Page_IsValid = true;
                }
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('<%= hdn.ClientID %>').value = "0";
                Page_IsValid = true;
            }
            return true;
        });
    });
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblstTest" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow"
            runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server" />
        <asp:CustomValidator ClientIDMode="Static" ID="cust" OnServerValidate="testSeverValidation"
            ClientValidationFunction="testClientValidation" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Error!"
            runat="server" />
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkSubmit" Text="Submit" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdn" runat="server" Value="0" />
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

---

For More information please check from Reference **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_clientside)**
[image][image]

Comment: On looking at your code. below are some comments. a) You need not set the display for the validators. As placed in your reference section ValidatorValidate method will do that. b) Your client validation function need not return true / false. c) You are not supposed to manipulate Page_IsValid from your code. It will be processed by ValidatorValidate and other framework code. d) Lot of code for no reason.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. So, now can you make necessary amendments in my code ? So that the control need not to move in server on either clicking yes or No.